TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'missing_cat'
TypeError: init() got an unexpected keyword argument 'missing_cat'
I am working on Autoclean, while adding missing_cat='auto', i am getting TypeError,
Can any one help to how to resolve this error as i have categorical data in my dataset

Without more information or a code sample it's going to be difficult to know where that error comes from. And assuming you're using python, adding the tag would help.
That aside, I've found those are often misspellings or issues with keyword arguments.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
